# How do I pin a website to the dock in OS X?

Tags: dock, websites

In Windows, and every permutation of Linux I've tried, you can pin a website as a icon shortcut to the dock / start menu / quick menu.

How can I do this in OSX? I use a habitica for my to-do list and I need a one-click entry to it all times

Answer (score 1):

Okay I just found a way.

You have to drag the website from Firefox left-hand side of the URL bar to your desktop. It will make a new file.

Move it into a permanent location, like Documents. Then drag that to the RIGHT-side of the dock. It will pin. Oddly it won't let you arrange it in the order you want to. It must stay on the right.

But the only catch is you cannot delete the file in Documents. If you do, it'll just show a question mark when you click the pinned icon.

Comment: With the exception of the Trash, you can arrange Dock Tiles any way you want on either side of the Dock Separator, however only Applications are allowed on the left side of the Dock Separator and why other object types must go to the right of the Dock Separator. If you want to have a Dock Tile for the document then use an AppleScript or Automator application bundle to open the document.  Then it can be on the left side of the Dock Separator.  You can create an app to open the link directly in a Browser, don't even need the link you dragged to the Desktop and put in Documents.

Comment: So simple it's complicated. That's Apple for ya